# Error in linear algebra proof

Tags: linear-algebra

In "The linear algebra a beginning graduate student ought to know" by Golan there is a proof that if $V$ is a vector space of over a field $F$ and $D$ is a maximal linearly-independent subset of $V$ then $D$ is a basis of $V$:

Assume that $D$ is a maximal linearly-independent subset of $V$, let $v_0 \in V \setminus D$, by hypothesis we know that $D \cup \{v_0\}$ is linearly dependent so $0_V \in F(D \cup \{v_0\}) \setminus F D$ and by exchange property this implies that $v_0 \in F (D \cup \{0_V\}) = F D$ so $D$ spans $V$.

But isn't wrong that $0_V \in F(D \cup \{v_0\}) \setminus F D$, since $0_V \in F D$? Am I missing something? Is there an easy way to "recover" this proof?

Note:

$F D$ is the linear span of the set $D$.

The exchange property is that if $v, w \in V$ and $D$ is a subset of $V$ satisfying $v \in F(D \cup \{w\}) \setminus F D$ then $w \in F(D \cup \{v\})$

Answer (score 0):

$0_V\in F(D\cup\{v_o\})$ because adding the vector $v_o$ to the maximal linearly independent set $D$ makes the set $D\cup \{v_o\}$ linearly dependent.

Comment: ... Yes, and why does that help? $\;$

Comment: $0_V$ is in any subspace of $V$ so $0_V$ is also in $F D$ and therefore it should not be in $F(D \cup \{v_0\}) \setminus F D$, right?

Comment: this means that you can find a linear combination of $D\cup \{v_o\}$ where they come out to 0 (because they are linearly dependent now). Obviously this is not in $FD$, so it must be in $D\cup\{v_o\} / FD$. I think this may be going under the assumption that $FD$ does not contain the trivial linear combination equal to zero. But I don't have the book so I can't be sure.

Comment: I think the book didn't go under this assumption, since it says also that $F D$ is a subspace of $V$, defines $F \emptyset = \{0_V\}$ and says that if $A \subset B$ then $F A \subset F B$, so you have at least two different ways to conclude that $0_V \in F D$ forall $D \subset V$.